# DOMParser for android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, inputstream, android-parser

Im leaning how to use DOm parser for android well I use the Servivce of example androidHive.com

**"http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml"**

Im using URLCOnnection to connect to a server which it has a username and password to connect but it  returns nullPointerException.

protected static InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
try{

```
 URLConnection UrlConn = url.openConnection();
 UrlConn.setDoInput (true);
    UrlConn.setRequestProperty ("trust",
            URLEncoder.encode(User,Pass);
    UrlConn .connect ();

    return UrlConn.getInputStream();



} catch (IOException e) {
    return null;
} catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
}
```

here is my code:

```
public static void domparser() throws Exception {
            //Get the DOM Builder Factory
         pizza=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); 

         String urlN="http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
         URL url=new URL(urlN);
         DocumentBuilderFactory factory = 
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

            //Get the DOM Builder
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document document = 
                      builder.parse(getInputStream(url));
            Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList nodeList = root.getElementsByTagName("menu");

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node=nodeList.item(i);
               NodeList list=node.getChildNodes();



                for(int x=0;list.getLength()>x;x++){
                    //map=new HashMap<String,String>();
                    HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
                    Node element=list.item(x);
                    String name=element.getNodeName();
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("id")){
                        map.put("Id",element.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().toString());
                    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
                        map.put("name",element.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().toString());
                    }
                    pizza.add(map);
                    }

            }


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your http client code throws an excetion during network access and returned the null value in one of your catch-blocks?
Reasons could be that no internet connection is available, permissions are missing in the AndroidManifest.xml, the wrong request method is used or problems with the timeout occurred.
Maybe debugging or logging the request code, the catch-blocks and the response entity could be useful for finding the core problem. In [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) article example code for checking the internet connection by using the ConnectivityManager system service and http connection is available.